# Netbeans debug error for JSF application

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I'm trying to do this tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-intro.html#template, but have problems with step 8 - debugging. I can deploy the application without any errors.

While deployment, I only encounter some warnings:

warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

3 warnings

but the application gets deployed and runs fine.

However, I've got problems when it comes to debugging. I right-click my project -> Debug, and get the following error:

org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.DebuggerStartException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.JPDADebuggerImpl.waitRunning(JPDADebuggerImpl.java:404)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.JPDADebuggerImpl.waitRunning(JPDADebuggerImpl.java:386)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.JPDADebugger.attach(JPDADebugger.java:324)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAConnect$1.run(JPDAConnect.java:235)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.attach(SocketTransportService.java:222)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.GenericAttachingConnector.attach(GenericAttachingConnector.java:116)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketAttachingConnector.attach(SocketAttachingConnector.java:90)
    at org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.AttachingDICookie.getVirtualMachine(AttachingDICookie.java:231)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.actions.StartActionProvider.doStartDebugger(StartActionProvider.java:188)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.actions.StartActionProvider.access$200(StartActionProvider.java:80)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.actions.StartActionProvider$1.run(StartActionProvider.java:165)
    ... 4 more
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

And the Debugger Console says:

Attaching to localhost:0

Connection refused.

I tried enabling debugging in GlassFish server.
How can I fix it and make the debugger work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...it didn't work because the server wasn't started in debug mode. I selected debug mode, restarted Glassfish and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine it's mean that your server is not working

Answer (score 0):

Starts "System Symbol" as Administrator
(Windows+R -> CMD (Run as Administrator))

Using DOS commands locates the folder where the GlassFish server is installed and accesses its Bin folder.

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\bin>
```

Then run the following command:

```
asadmin start-domain --debug
```

Then... in NetBeans IDE opens the "Debug" menu and enters the "Attach Debugger" option, a window will be displayed where you will be asked for the server port and timeout, by default the GlassFish port is 4848 and a sufficient timeout is 1000 [ms] , click "OK"

And now you can debug your project, just press "Ctrl+F5" or the menu option "Debug Project"

I hope you will use this solution, I was able to solve the same problem using the steps I detailed.